How do we know the predicate $\text{Proof}(x,y)$ exists?
On a proof (sketch) of Gödel's Incompleteness Theorems, the following predicate is defined and used:

Let $\text{Proof}(x, y)$ be a binary predicate that translates "$x$ is the Gödel number of a proof of a formula whose Gödel number is $y$".

How does the author know that there is a formula $\text{Proof}(x,y)$ with that property?

To create such a  a predicate, all you need to combine is things like "the $k$th line of the proof follows from lines $i$ and $j$ by rule number $m$ from the list of rules of inference" and "the $k$th line of the proof is an axiom". If you can turn these into predicates, then forming the Proof predicate is a simple exercise. And if you cannot, it certainly means that your rules of inference and/or set of axioms is not effectively enumerable. And indeed, if your axioms come from a mysterious crystal ball, it may happen that your theory is complete.
